# Is it possible to force update of Route53 DNS resolver cache in AWS when IP changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, internal-dns, amazon-route53, aws-cli

I have several VPC's set up in AWS, and all of my instances use provisioned IP addresses, that is - *not* using `Elastic IP Addresses`.

When any given instance boots up, it executes a script on the machine (post networking), which gets the Instance ID, Zone ID (from local config), and region, etc - once it has this information, it updates `Route 53` to update the DNS information in a private hosted zone for these instances.

The reason for this is basically so that I can use DNS for server connection strings. I have my Web server and DB servers in a private subnet, and when the Web Server connects to the DB - it just uses the `staticdns.mydomain.private` which maps to the instance private IP address. This way, it doesn't require an amount of reconfiguration when the instance gets rebooted or if the IP changes for other reasons.

This is all well and good, and it works - with one caveat. There is a delay in the resolving of the new DNS mappings, I am not sure how long it is - it isn't VERY long, but it seems to be somewhat random (TTL maybe?). For this period that the resolver has the *OLD* IP cached, we will get connection failures from Web Server to the Database. I would much prefer that this cache was released when it was updated, but I have no clue where to even search for that.

Does anyone know if there is a way to refresh the DNS resolver cache within private zones in Route 53? I have tried using `nscd` also on the server, which did not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of options and notes...

1. If the servers are in the same VPC or in peered VPCs use their private IPs for communication, not the public ones. Private IPs stay the same when instance is stopped/restarted.
2. The old records are cached on the hosts, not in Route 53. You'd have to flush the `nscd` cache all the other hosts once one IP has changed, that's quite a lot of automation to be done. Besides some apps and frameworks also cache the records outside of nscd so it's quite hard to flush everything when needed.
3. You can lower the TTL of your DNS records to 60 (= 1 minute), that means the resolved records won't be cached for more than a minute. That's the same approach that AWS RDS uses for a fail-over mechanism.
4. Use [Network Load Balancer (NLB)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-network-load-balancer-effortless-scaling-to-millions-of-requests-per-second/) - it will provide a stable IP for your server even if the server's actual IP changes. However it's quite an overkill.
5. Use *Elastic IPs*. That would solve your problem too. They cost nothing when attached to a running instance.
6. Use AWS RDS, possibly [*Serverless Aurora*](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) that costs next to nothing when not in use. All the management, failover, etc will be done for you.

Comment: I *am* using the private IP addresses. These are set to the private internal zone in route53, mapping the private internal IP addresses, not the public ones. They do not even have public ones

Comment: Aurora is a money pit! It was much cheaper to spin up an EC2 c5.large and load mysql on it! Like HUNDREDS cheaper.

Comment: Also - can you use elastic IP's in a private/internal manner? I thought they were external/public IP addresses, and they come at a cost also.

Comment: @BarryChapman why would a private IP change..? Mine almost never change unless I’m running out of IPs in the subnet while the instance is down. In which case a larger subnet is the answer.

Comment: If you are in a scalable set, where you build and drop instances ad-hoc using chef or other tools, then this is a very viable scenario.

Comment: @BarryChapman in that case NLB is the way to go. When the new instance boots up it registers itself to NLB and nothing has to change on the clients. They only know the NLB IPs.

Comment: @MLu something I don't see mentioned is that Route 53 requires ~35 seconds between the time you send an RR changeset to its API and the time its *authoritative* servers all begin returning the new data, and that delay simply can't be avoided.  Officially, the objective for this intra-Route 53 propagation/activation is 60 seconds, see https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/.